# c# Stream Writer output

Tags: c#

```
StreamWriter sWrite = new StreamWriter("Data.txt", true);
 string strWrite = txtID.Text + ","
                              + txtName + ","
                              + txtAdress;`enter code here`
            sWrite.WriteLine(strWrite);
            sWrite.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Person Added");
```

this is my code, why the output looks like this?

```
(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: Yasser,System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: Jeddah,202)
```

Comment: `txtName` should most likly be `txtName.Text` , same for `txtAdress`

Comment: It s missing some code ; what do you call "output" ?

Comment: Typo?  You're referencing the `.Text` property of *one* of your text boxes, but not the other two.  It looks like you simply forgot on the other two...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to write the contents of a `TextBox` to a string, you need to use the `TextBox.Text` property to access the content.

In your attempt you have used the `Text` property of the `txtID` `TextBox` control correctly, but not the others. The default output of any *object* when you concatenate it into a string is to call the `.ToString()` method on that object, by default this will return the *name* of the *type* of that object. `TextBox` however overrides this base and returns the name of the *type* as well as the content of the default property which is the `.Text` property. That is why we see `"System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: Jeddah"` in the output.

*We do not need to assume that those controls are textboxes, this output confirms it for us*. Therefore, we would expect the following code to produce output similar to your expectations:

```
string strWrite = txtID.Text + ","
                    + txtName.Text + ","
                    + txtAdress.Text;
```

I can't explain why your example output text is in the reverse order though, so I doubt that this output matches the code you have posted as it is.